# Pay my visit to some place

Tags: grammar

"Pay a visit to" is regarded as an idiomatic expression. My question: Is it correct to say "pay my/your visit to some place"? Is the sentence "I should pay my first visit to your work place" correct?

Comment: In some areas of the UK (BrE) 'pay a visit' means to go to the toilet.

Comment: "My" might be used when the purpose of the specific visit has been established or is known in context.   "I'm going to go pay my visit to Aunt Ethel.  I have to see her every time I'm in town or my mother gets mad at me."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying "pay my visit" isn't incorrect, but it doesn't mean the same thing as "pay a visit".

In particular, saying "pay my visit" only makes sense when the listener is already aware of some visit, and you want to talk about *that* visit.

These examples of "my visit" are okay because the listener's attention has already been brought to some visit:

- I visit the patients myself. I usually pay my visits in the evening. = *When I make those visits*, I usually do it in the evening.
- I am going to visit a bunch of office buildings. I should pay my first visit to your workplace. = *When I make the first of those visits*, it should be at your workplace.
- I am visiting the house of everyone in the neighborhood. Tomorrow I should pay my visit to your house. = *When I make the visit to your house*, it should be tomorrow.

Generally, you can't say "pay my visit" if you haven't previously mentioned the visit that you're talking about (or brought the visit to the listener's attention in some other way).

Comment: "Pay a visit" resembles other phrases like "take a trip", "have a nap", "take a holiday", "take a break", etc. It's often far from obvious which expressions use "my" and which use "a" or "the", but there's nothing very strange about it.

Answer (score 0):

**pay a visit**

> Frequently in the phrases to make, or pay (also †give) **a visit**, to
>   return **a visit**. [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/223957?redirectedFrom=pay%20a%20visit#eid15370062)

Your question:

> Can I say "I should pay my visit to your house"

Better would be:

"I should pay **a** visit to your house"

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example from a fiction book (*Ne'er Do Well, by Dornford Yates - House of Stratus, 2011, UK*):

> ... I visit the patients myself. I usually **pay my visits** between five and
>   six in the evening...

Comment: Thanks. Can I say "I should pay my visit to your house" ?

Comment: Probably, that would need a context of a visit by appointment (or one of the regular visits, e. g. by some inspector).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, "pay a visit" is an idiomatic expression commonly used when referring to visiting a place or person. It is perfectly acceptable to say "pay my/your visit to some place." The sentence "I should pay my first visit to your work place" is also correct, and it means that the speaker intends to visit the other person's workplace for the first time.